# Prometheus alert CPUThrottlingHigh raised but monitoring does not show it

Tags: docker, kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus

I have installed Prometheus to monitor my installation and it is frequently raising alerts about CPU throttling.

The Prometheus alert rules to identify this alert is :

```
alert: CPUThrottlingHigh
expr: 100
  * sum by(container_name, pod_name, namespace) (increase(container_cpu_cfs_throttled_periods_total{container_name!=""}[5m]))
  / sum by(container_name, pod_name, namespace) (increase(container_cpu_cfs_periods_total[5m]))
  > 25
for: 15m
```

If I look at one of the pods identified by this alert, it does not seem to have any reason to throttle :

```
$ kubectl top pod -n monitoring my-pod
NAME            CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
my-pod          0m           6Mi
```

This pod has one container with these resources setup :

```
Limits:
  cpu:     100m
  memory:  128Mi
Requests:
  cpu:     25m
  memory:  64Mi
```

And the node that is hosting this pod is not under any heavy cpu use :

```
$ kubectl -n monitoring top node aks-agentpool-node-1
NAME                       CPU(cores)   CPU%      MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%   
aks-agentpool-node-1       853m         21%       11668Mi         101%
```

On grafana, if I look at the chart for this pod, it never goes above `0,000022` of cpu usage

Why is it throttling ?

Comment: Have you validated that you need to multiple by 100? Is it a decimal format for the percentage or an integer value?

Comment: I am not sure to understand. The expression `100m` is the same as `0.1` cpu.

Comment: If that's the syntax for Prometheus then disregard. Was just checking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `CPUThrottlingHigh` is an alert created by the [kubernetes-mixin](https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin) project. There is an open issue ([#108](https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/issues/108)) to discuss this alert. I suggest that you read all the comments on this issue to better understand the problem.

In short, the problem is: When working with low CPU limits, spiky workloads can have low averages and still be being throttled.

Also, take a look at this issue ([#67577](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/67577)) from Kubernetes project, which addresses a Kernel bug in CFS quotas that may cause unnecessary CPU throttling. The discussion is still open, and the Kubernetes project are even considering disabling CFS quotas for pods in the [`Guaranteed` QoS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/#create-a-pod-that-gets-assigned-a-qos-class-of-guaranteed) (see [#70585](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/70585) for reference).

Consider the following options:

- Increase (or even remove) your container CPU limits
- Disable Kubernetes CFS quotas entirely
  (kubelet's flag `--cpu-cfs-quota=false`)
- Use a Kernel version that contains this fix ([torvalds/linux 512ac99](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/512ac999d2755d2b7109e996a76b6fb8b888631d))

Comment: Thanks, it is nice to know that the issue is not on my installation. I don't want to increase or remove limits for now. And I am using AKS (a managed implementation of Kubernetes in Azure cloud) so I cannot disable CFS quotas. As per the comments in the issue, I am going to try to update the kernel version to see what happens.

Comment: @jobou, have you update a kernel version? Was it helpful?

Comment: No sorry, I have not worked on this issue yet so I don't have any real feedback to give.

Comment: We are still eeing this exact same thing in Dec 2020 and we are running on GKE 1.16.15.4300.  Our requests and limits are quite a bit higher than the ones in the question.  Removing CPU limits is not really an option for us.

Answer (score 2):

To piggy back off of @eduardo-baitello answer, A third option is to increase the `CPUThrottlingPercent` config [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-monitoring/kubernetes-mixin/blob/f7ca48cca5d9cadc9a2203b8c0b3bb3eb85f3294/config.libsonnet#L44)

Comment: Mind posting this as a comment?